# Can I set up Samba so Windows clients connect to the Linux share with their AD password?

Tags: linux, windows, samba

Both my Windows and Linux users authenticate with a common Active Directory (AD) username/password.  Each Windows user that will mount the share, also has a Linux account on the Samba host.  Can I configure the Samba server to use the remote AD authentication rather than having any password store local to the Linux server?  I'm using Red Hat Enterprise Linux Workstation release 7.5.

Comment: All you have to do is have the Samba server authenticate via Active Directory in the same way that the Windows and Linux machines do and then assign the samba and file permissions via the AD groups and users.

Comment: @NasirRiley. No doubt you are correct since that is the obvious answer, but I was looking for some direction as to how this may be accomplished. Can you provide such a clue?

Comment: In the same way that the other Linux machines are authenticating via Active Directory. Look at the configs on those machines and do the same thing on the Samba server.

Comment: Just google samba and AD, there are tons of step by step instructions like https://www.howtoforge.com/samba_active_directory